# Android layout: variable-width view between two fixed-width views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

How does one lay out 3 views horizontally such that the outer 2 views are of fixed width and the middle view fills the remaining available horizontal space?  All of my attempts to do this have resulted in the rightmost view being pushed off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for a while to get this working and found how how to do it with `RelativeLayout`.  See code example below and pay close attention to the usage of `layout_toRightOf`, `layout_toLeftOf`, and `layout_alignParentRight`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/eventDetailSectionHeight"
    android:background="@color/grayout">

    <SomeFixedWidthView
        android:id="@+id/leftFixedWidthView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <SomeVariableWidthView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leftFixedWidthView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightFixedWidthView"/>

    <SomeFixedWidthView
        android:id="@+id/rightFixedWidthView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting layout_weight for each child according to requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">


        <View
            android:id="@+id/leftView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff0000"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/middleView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#33cc33"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/rightView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff0000"/>/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for your desired result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/leftView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff0000"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/middleView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#33cc33"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/rightView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff0000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```